# Wrong warning in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, warnings

The Android studio shows the warning "method setFoo is never used" in the code bellow:

```
public void setFoo(float foo) {
    mFoo = foo;
    invalidate();
}

protected void startFooProcess() {
    ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(this, "foo", 1.0f, 0.0f);
    animator.setDuration(getResources().getInteger(android.R.integer.config_longAnimTime));
    animator.setTarget(this);
    animator.start();
}
```

But I`m using it with object animator, How to supress this kind of warning?

Comment: you can add @SuppressWarnings({"UnusedDeclaration"})

Answer (score 4):

> File > Invalidate caches / Restart

to fix this problem

You can see this [enter link description here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=180825)

Comment: Thanks this worked for me, it was driving me nuts :)

Answer (score 1):

If you click on the `setFoo` method name you'll get a yellow lightbulb icon which you can click on for quickfix icons. As a shortcut, with the caret in the method name, you can use the key combo for "Show Intention Actions", which is Alt+Enter on the default Mac keymap that I use.

The quickfix "Safe delete 'setFoo(float)'" isn't what you want, but you can expand that to see more options either via the keyboard or by clicking the right arrow. That shows you options you can use to disable the inspection. Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of UI for options for suppressing warnings]

Comment: This is more a problem than a solution, because the opions of supress for method create the annotation '@SuppressWarnings("UnusedDeclaration")' but this thing dirty the code, the options supress for class do the same thing for all class and disable option is not a good ideia because it turns impossible to find true not used methods...

Comment: While all that's true, I'm not sure what you can reasonably expect here. You've got lots of different choices for disabling the inspection, each with benefits and drawbacks. About the only other thing I could think of would be to include a dummy class or method somewhere that makes calls to the method to work around the inspection, but that also has drawbacks.

Comment: Yes I agree, and what I expect is a solution that don't change the source code. For example, I have other troubles with lint that I have fixed with some configurations in the lint.xml file in app root folder. Something like it I see as a good solution.

Comment: the inspections seem to work only half of the time. I even get warnings on public methods that they aren't used in the same class/package...ridiculous.

Comment: @slinden77 I still got this issue after updating to version 2.1.3. Is this a bug of Android Studio? Drove me crazy.

Comment: @JamesZhao there is indeed a issue filed about this, I consider it a bug, even though it is probably intended as a good feature. Turning of the inspection on unused public methods is probably the way to go

Comment: @slinden77 It is a bug. Use File > Invalidate caches to fix this problem - but this will clear your local file history. See this https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=180825